# How does one view what the contents of symbolic link are, instead of the destination?

Tags: symlink

Is there some way in which I can view/edit what the contents of a symbolic link are? I don't want to view the destination the link points to, but the symbolic link itself.

Suppose I have a file, `file.txt` and I create a link to `file.txt` as

```
    ln -s $HOME/path/to/file.txt .
```

Now, if I copy this link to a different system, this link will point to nothing if `$HOME` expands to something different on the other system, even if the path after `$HOME` is still the same. Is there some way to edit the link file so that `$HOME` is not expanded before creating the file, but is a part of the file itself?

Comment: Symbolic links don't store variable names. Your shell is expanding the variable before it gets to the `ln` executable. If you tried to copy it, `cp` would follow the link and copy the target. You can merely instruct `cp` to copy the link if that's what you want too.

Comment: @Gilles: Dynamic Symlinks are what I need! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

`readlink` will show you the content of the link, but the destination is all there is.

You can't put variables in a symbolic link, but you can make the paths relative. So if you have:

```
$HOME/path/to/file.txt
$HOME/other/path/to/symlink.txt
```

You could create the symlink as `../../../path/to/file.txt`, it will point to `file.txt` regardless of what `$HOME` is.

```
ln -s ../../../path/to/file.txt $HOME/other/path/to/symlink.txt
```