# How to treat a symbolic link as a file itself (instead of the one it points to)?

Tags: shell, symlink, coreutils

Out of curiosity i wanted to open a symlink as itself instead of the file it points to, just to see how it looks like. While there are ways to see what file it points to like using `readlink` and ways to copy symlinks themselves like `cp -P`, none of these allow you to see the actual contents of the symlink.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? (either in plain text or in hexadecimal)

Comment: Related - [How does one view what the contents of symbolic link are, instead of the destination?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83017/100397) and [Actual content of a symlink file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/609474/100397) and maybe possibly [is there a way to see the actual contents of a symlink?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4572805/2344631). None is a strict duplicate

Comment: What? `readlink` reads the actual contents of the symlink. A symlink doesn't necessarily point to a file; it can be dangling. `readlink` will read whatever is in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symlinks don't have any other content beside the link target, which you'd read with `readlink()`.

As for symlink's metainfo. check [`lstat()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat).

`lstat()`  is  identical to `stat()`, except that if pathname is a symbolic link, then it returns
information about the link itself, not the file that it refers to.